# How do I store data from an api in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm completely new to python and have little coding experience. I've thus far managed to get the data from my API stored in noncompliant_data but I don't know how to take that data and store it in my MySQL database. Everything I've seen so far seems to require that I have an insert statement with each row manually included. With hundreds of rows that's not really efficient I don't think. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
import mysql.connector

response = requests.get("redactedAPIURL")

noncompliant_data = response.text

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="mypassword",
            database="database_name",


)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to query the data later.

If all you want to do is save the whole data as a long text string to be fetched later in its entirety, then you could store it as is:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable SET textcolumn = %s",
  [noncompliant_data])
connection.commit()
```

(`mytable` and `textcolumn` are just examples. You should replace these with the names of your table and its column.)

But if that's all you need, then you might not need an SQL database at all. You could just save the content to a file.

If you're using SQL, the likely reason is that you need more flexibility later to query subsets of the data using SQL expressions and logic. For that, the best way is to store the data in multiple rows, and each row has multiple columns.

Comment: Gotcha, for further context I am wanting to use this data for a couple things. First I'm wanting to use the data in my name column to query a directory API to get emails addresses. From there I'm wanting to be able to send automated emails every 30 days and  a specified date to the people who's names are in the first table and include some of the information from that table. I'm having to do it this way because the directory API requires at least three characters to pull the persons information.

Comment: Okay it's hard to visualize that without seeing a sample of the data, and the result you want. But the point is it sounds like you have some cases where it would be an advantage to store the data in multiple rows and columns. So do that.